# Groovy file.append() vs file.newWriter()

Tags: file, groovy

I have written several Groovy programs that write flat files using file.write() and file.append() or simply "file << string".  I recently came across some information when researching this method where people said that this may be inefficient as appending to a file means the append opens the file, finds the end, writes to it, and closes it each time the append is called.  In some programs I may call this numerous times as I write to a file after selecting data from a database.

I further read that using a file writer is more efficient, for example declaring

```
fileWriter = new file.newWriter()
```

and then issuing

```
fileWriter.write()
```

instead.  My question is, what are other people doing and does anybody know at about what point it would be worth considering a change to using a file writer instead?  I haven't actually noticed a performance hit to this point; however, I have several more programs to write that will produce some large flat files and if it makes sense to use the file writer I'd rather change my previous programs to use it now rather than later.

Comment: When You often write small chunks to a file, I suppose it's better to use writer. In case of rare writes of bigger portions I'll pick whats more comfortable for development.

Comment: Thanks Opal, I think you might be right.  I did some benchmarking and printed the times and the more writes I do the more time it takes.  It seems to be only a matter of a few seconds for up to 10,000 writes but that might make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple benchmark to illustrate the problem:

```
@Grab(group='org.gperfutils', module='gbench', version='0.4.2-groovy-2.1')

def b = benchmark {
      'append' {
          def f = File.createTempFile('file', 'append')
          (1..1000).each {
              f.append(it.toString())
          }
      }
      'writer' {
          def f = File.createTempFile('file', 'writer')
          def w = f.newWriter()
          (1..1000).each {
              w.write(it.toString())
          }
      }
}
b.prettyPrint()
```